# Magento admin not logging in UAT server, no error

Tags: php, magento, phpmyadmin, magento-1.4

I am trying to login to magento admin, but the page flickers and doesn't login.
Even there are no error messages in console.

What could be the possible reason.

I'm facing this in the UAT server of my site. (URL something like: https ://uat.mysite.com/control for admin)

Googled almost all the 10 pages in google.

**Below are the checks done:**

1. No errors in console.
2. Checked etc/local xml file for configurations- Seems right
3. Gave 0777 permission to var folder - Not helping
4. Checked server space- Space is plenty
5. Tried deleted session for past 7 days :  find var/session -name 'sess_*' -type f -mtime +7 -delete
6. Referred below pages:

   - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/26071/magento-1-9-can-t-login-to-admin-panel
   - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/94589/keeping-customers-logged-in-after-deleting-var-session-in-magento
7. Finally tried changing the core Varien.php file, knowing its not the safe method --- no use there too

Commenting the last 3 lines in **app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Session\Abstract\Varien.php**

```
  $cookieParams = array(
        'lifetime' => $cookie->getLifetime(),
        'path'     => $cookie->getPath(),
        'domain'   => $cookie->getConfigDomain(),
        'secure'   => $cookie->isSecure(),
        'httponly' => $cookie->getHttponly()
    );
```

Comment: have u seen httpd error log ?

Answer (score 0):

Open your database and play that request:

```
select * from core_config_data where path like "%cookie%";
```

If you have the old url, change it!